# How to set MaxSelectedItems property of kendo Multiselect dynamically in Javascript

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

net mvc and i want to set the MaxSelectedItems property of Kendo Multiselect based on some codition dynamically using javascript. refer code snip below. Thanks in Advance.

@Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.Name)

In my javascript

```
if(condition)
{    
    $(#Name).MaxSelectedItems(1);
}
```

the JS is not working

Answer (score 3):

Try doing:

```
if (condition) {
    var ms = $("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    ms.options.maxSelectedValue = 6;
}
```

Example:

```js
$("#required").kendoMultiSelect({
  maxSelectedItems : 4
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");

$("#change6").on("click", function() {
  var sel = $("#required").data("kendoMultiSelect");
  sel.options.maxSelectedItems = 6;
}); 
$("#change4").on("click", function() {
  var sel = $("#required").data("kendoMultiSelect");
  sel.options.maxSelectedItems = 4;
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<button id="change6" class="k-button">Change to 6</button><br/>
<button id="change4" class="k-button">Change to 4</button><br/>
<select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
  <option>Steven White</option>
  <option>Nancy King</option>
  <option>Nancy Davolio</option>
  <option>Robert Davolio</option>
  <option>Michael Leverling</option>
  <option>Andrew Callahan</option>
  <option>Michael Suyama</option>
  <option selected>Anne King</option>
  <option>Laura Peacock</option>
  <option>Robert Fuller</option>
  <option>Janet White</option>
  <option>Nancy Leverling</option>
  <option>Robert Buchanan</option>
  <option>Margaret Buchanan</option>
  <option selected>Andrew Fuller</option>
  <option>Anne Davolio</option>
  <option>Andrew Suyama</option>
  <option>Nige Buchanan</option>
  <option>Laura Fuller</option>
</select>
```

Comment: HI OnaBai thank you for the answer. But in my code iam not using the <select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees..."> instead iam binding directly from the database. @Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.User).Name("User").DataTextField("Text").DataValueField("Value").DataSource(
    dataSource => dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("GetUser", "User"))) and my id is #user

Comment: That's not a problem. The only thing that you need to do in your JavaScript code is getting a reference to the MultiSelect (you probably know the name) and then do as in my example.

Answer (score -1):

```
 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
            .Name("ArenaList2")
            .Placeholder("Select attendees...")
            .BindTo(Model.ArenaList)
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .MaxSelectedItems(3)
 )
```

You can configure it in the control itself with this option   **.MaxSelectedItems(3)**

Comment: The question is about setting the `MaxSelectedItems` property conditionally.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.